# Ember.js current link not marked as "active" when access by direct url visit from browser

Tags: ember.js

I have the following minimal app.

Main container has a link to "Todos". When I click "Todos" link it gets a class `active` and becomes red by following the according css rule. When I submit `#/todos` url in my browser it loads the correct template with "Todos" link marked with class `active`.

The problem appears with the nested object links.

When I follow link to a specific todo it renders a `todo` template and marks the link red. But when I submit `#/todos/1` url in my browser it responds with the correct template with the correct model (it shows the id), but link doesn't have a class `active`.

So my problem is that by submitting url `#/todos/1` in browser the according link doesn't get a class `active`.

JSBin: http://jsbin.com/vopajaro/1#/todos/2

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.js"></script>
        <script src="http://builds.handlebarsjs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/handlebars-1.0.0.js"></script>
        <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/tags/v1.3.0/ember.js"></script>

        <script src="app.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
            {{#link-to "todos"}}Todos{{/link-to}}
            {{outlet}}
        </script>

        <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="todos">
            {{#each}}
                {{#link-to "todo" this}}{{id}}{{/link-to}}
            {{/each}}
            {{outlet}}
        </script>

        <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="todo">
            {{id}}
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('todos', function() {
    this.resource('todo', { path: ":id" });
  });
});

App.TodosRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return [{id: 1, name: 'todo 1'}, {id: 2, name: 'todo 2'}];
  }
});
```

**app.css**

```
a.active {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: It seems to be working fine for me: http://jsbin.com/vopajaro/1/

Comment: Does it work when you follow http://jsbin.com/vopajaro/1#/todos/2 ?

Comment: I see your problem. It works when you click the links, but not when you manually alter the hash. Not sure what to make of that. It might be an Ember bug.

Comment: Did you get it to work?